# WPF Client with WCF Service from Localhost dev to prod server?

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf, mvvm

I am just starting to learn WCF. I have successfully set up a WCF service with host console app. The service maps to SQL Server with Entity Framework. I then have a WPF client app which consumes the service. This all works fine in Dev, both the service and client app running from my machine:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRegimesService" contract="RegimesService.IRegimesService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IRegimesService" />
```

I have now transferred the service and host onto my new VM. The service host runs fine. I am now trying to configure the client app endpoint to connect to the service. I think the HTTP address is incorrect:

Service app.config:

```
  <services>
   <service name="diiRegimesService.RegimesService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="diiRegimesService.IRegimesService"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8082" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Client app.config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://emea-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com/localhost:8082/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRegimesService" contract="RegimesService.IRegimesService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IRegimesService" />
</client>
```

The server credentials for remote desktop are: `emea-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com`
I currently don't specify a username & password in my client app.config.

The service is running on the server. I'm getting an exception trying to add the service reference in the client app.

Add Service Reference- Adress: `http://EMEA-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com`

```
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://emea-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com/'.
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the server is able to resolve the full domain name.

Also, the address url provided in the client configuration snippet `<endpoint address="http://emea-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com/localhost:8082/` does not seem valid.  Perhaps you want to use `<endpoint address="http://emea-myserver01.emea.basketballinfo.com:8082/`

Comment: Thanks @Seymour, the Add Service Reference wizard now accepts the address & searches but doesn't return the service despite the service running on the server, getting a timed out exception.

Comment: You may want to enable WCF Tracing and review the log .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx